# When is it good to use both DTOs and Breeze?

Tags: breeze, single-page-application

I've built my WebAPI to serve DTOs to the client as a means of separating the domain models from the client-side models.  I'm now ramping on client-side technologies like Breeze and I'm wondering how using Breeze would affect this pattern, and if it's an either/or kind of scenario.  When is it a good idea to use both breeze and DTOs, if ever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breeze doesn't really care whether you want to use a DTO or a more full fledged domain model 'Entity' object.  From a .NET perspective, Breeze can apply its full range of query services to any collection that can be exposed as an IEnumerable or an IQueryable. If you don't want to use queries, you can expose individual DTO's or collections of DTO's via WebApi methods that take parameters.

You also have the option of using Breeze queries with projections to construct DTO objects from entities on the server and only work with the DTO's on the client.

If querying is important to you, then the primary issue with DTO's vs domain model 'Entities' from your perspective is how easy it is for you to expose your DTO's as 'Queryable' objects and how efficient this querying is likely to be.  Many ORM tools, like Entity Framework, are able to transform a query so that most of the heavy processing is performed by the Database engine. Such optimizations can be very performant in comparison to the alternative of trying to iterate over a DTO collection in order to execute a query.

One interesting alternative is to use something like the Entity Framework and WebApi to expose only the mapped subset of your domain model that you want exposed on the client. i.e. you use the Entity Framework to do your DTO mapping for you.  So you have two EF models, a full domain model and a DTO domain model.  The advantage of this, is that you still get the advantage of query optimization.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Jay.  Right now my project uses EF and WebAPI to expose DTOs that I've manually mapped - I have a thin (no children) and thick (with children) DTO for each entity with toEntity and toDto methods.  Would you consider this overkill in light of libraries like Breeze that can just query a single DTO/model to get what's needed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but a single breeze query can return an entire graph of objects. i.e. a collection of parents and whichever children you select.